# Android: Adding new buttons after picture capture to accept/decline image

Tags: java, android, android-intent, sdk, android-camera

I'm still new to development, and I was wondering if someone can guide me towards the right direction in my situation because I'm not sure where to begin:

Scheme:

After pressing a `capture_button` to capture an image (`capture_button` and `imagePreview` is in same activity), I would like to remove the `capture_button`and have an `ACCEPT` or `DECLINE` button. These buttons are supposed to be `accept` the image and then save, or `decline` the image and go back to the imagePreview.

Now, I'm not sure if I'm supposed to create another activity when `capture_button` is pressed,

PhotoActivity.java

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.photo);

        mCamera = getCameraInstant();
        mCameraPreview = new CameraPreview(this, mCamera);

        FrameLayout preview = (FrameLayout) findViewById(id.camera_preview);
        preview.addView(mCameraPreview);

        // Add a listener to the Capture button
        Button captureButton = (Button) findViewById(id.button_capture);
        captureButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    // get an image from the camera
                    mCamera.takePicture(null, null, mPicture);

                }
            }
        );  
    }

PictureCallback mPicture = new PictureCallback(){
        @Override
        public void onPictureTaken(byte[] data, Camera camera) {
        Log.e("photo","pictureCallback");   
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            File pictureFile = getOutputMediaFile(MEDIA_TYPE_IMAGE);
            if(pictureFile==null){
                return;
            }
            try {
                FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(pictureFile);
                fos.write(data);
                fos.close();
            } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                Log.d(TAG, "File not found: " + e.getMessage());
            } catch (IOException e){
                Log.d(TAG, "Error accessing file: " + e.getMessage());
            }
        }
};

    private File getOutputMediaFile(int type){
        File mediaStorageDir = new File(Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(
                  Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES), "Photo");
        if (!mediaStorageDir.exists()){
            if (! mediaStorageDir.mkdirs()){
                Log.d("Photo", "failed to create directory");
                return null;
            }
        }
        // Create a media file name
        String timeStamp = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd_HHmmss").format(new Date());
        File mediaFile;
            mediaFile = new File(mediaStorageDir.getPath() + File.separator +
            "IMG_"+ timeStamp + ".jpg");
        return mediaFile;
    }
```

Now, am I supposed to do some kind of `Intent` after the `capture_button` click, or after

```
PictureCallback mPicture = new PictureCallback(){
```

and then have the `onPictureTaken` at the other activity? Or is my thinking all wrong?

Please help?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

try this it will help you

```
       final LinearLayout accept_deciline  = new LinearLayout(getApplicationContext());
       LayoutParams lp = new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
       accept_deciline.setOrientation(LinearLayout.HORIZONTAL);
       Button accept = new Button(getApplicationContext());
       accept.setText("Accept");
       Button decline = new Button(getApplicationContext());
       decline.setText("Decline");
       accept_deciline.addView(accept);
       accept_deciline.addView(decline);
       addContentView(accept_deciline, lp);
       accept_deciline.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);

       accept.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
           @Override
           public void onClick(View v) {
               // SAVE YOUR IMAGE.
           }
       });

       decline.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

           @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
            }
       });
       //KEEP THIS LINE IN YOUR PICTURE CALLBACK NOT HERE.
       accept_deciline.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
```

IT WILL BE BETTER IF YOU WILL CREATE YOUR ACCEPT DECLINE LAYOUT IN XML FILE AND MAKE IT INVISIBLE WHEN YOUR ON PICTURE TAKEN WILL BE CALLED JUST MAKE IT VISIBLE.

Answer (score 0):

One thing that I have done is to use an alertdialog that pops up after you take a picture. You can set the onclick listeners to perform any actions you need depending on what you want to happen(accept or decline). This would avoid the need to make any changes to your layouts and add buttons and take them away. You could launch the alertdialog by placing the alertdialog.show() method at the end of your onPictureTaken method.

If you do this youll have to have the filepath of the image you just took so you can allow a user to destroy it if they decline it and on some devices it may take the mediaservice a couple of seconds to update the images filepath so if you go to destroy an image it doesnt see you can get a force close. There are a couple ways to do this and I cant remember at the moment but one of them is way faster than the rest.

You wouldnt need an intent unless you plan on launching some other kind of action, activity, service, ect. For instance if you want to pass the filepath of the image to another activity where you can make changes to it, upload it, or what have you, you can add the filepath of the  image to an intent like this:
     intent.putExtra("imagepath",imagepath);